# Searching the Array Index & Element Equality

Tags: python, interview-questions, binary-search

I was asked this question from online coding interview and I have provided my solution that passes all of the test cases. I wanted to see if someone can review my code.

> Array Index & Element Equality
>
> Given a sorted array arr of distinct integers, write a function
> indexEqualsValueSearch that returns the lowest index i for which
> arr[i] == i. Return -1 if there is no such index. Analyze the time and
> space complexities of your solution and explain its correctness.
>
> Examples:
>
> input: arr = [-8,0,2,5] output: 2 # since arr[2] == 2
>
> input: arr = [-1,0,3,6] output: -1 # since no index in arr satisfies
> arr[i] == i.
>
> [input] array.integer arr [output]: interger

I think you can find this question through [this link](https://www.pramp.com/challenge/jKoA5GAVy9Sr9jGBjz04).

My implementation uses binary search, which gives me \$O(\log(N))\$ time complexity, and space complexity is \$O(1)\$ in my solution.

```
def index_equals_value_search(arr):
    left = 0
    right = len(arr) - 1

    ind = 0
    last = -1
    while left < right:
        ind = (left + right) // 2
        if arr[ind] - ind < 0:
            left = ind + 1
        elif arr[ind] == ind:
            right = ind - 1
            last = ind
        else:
            right = ind - 1
    if arr[left] == left:
        return left
    return last
```

Test cases:

```
Passed 6 Test cases:
Test Cases #1
Input: [0],Expected: 0,Actual: 0
Test Case #2
Input: [0,3],Expected: 0,Actual: 0
Test Case #3
Input: [-8,0,1,3,5],Expected: 3,Actual: 3
Test Case #4
Input: [-5,0,2,3,10,29],Expected: 2,Actual: 2
Test Case #5
Input: [-5,0,3,4,10,18,27],Expected: -1,Actual: -1
Test Case #6
Input: [-6,-5,-4,-1,1,3,5,7],Expected: 7,Actual: 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've made the right call in going with binary search for this problem. I agree that in terms of asymptotic complexity it is \$ O (log(n)) \$ in time and \$ O(1) \$ in space.

The line `ind = 0` is unnecessary because it will be reset 3 lines later before it's ever used.

The implementation seems broadly solid and you have your edge cases covered. I think you could simplify out that last `if arr[left] == left:` check by changing the loop condition to `while left <= right:`. That would mean the computer running a couple of unnecessary lines of code going through the loop one last time instead of you writing (and the computer parsing) a couple of unnecessary lines of code checking an edge case. I would probably favour the code uniformity, but there's not much in it.

I think if I was writing that innermost test block I'd do it slightly differently. I'd first check for equality and set last in the case of a match, and then independently (i.e. not in `elif`) check for which way to search. This just makes it easier to see what you are doing, in terms of record running best and continue search. Something that looks a bit like this

```
    if arr[ind] == ind:
        last = ind # found a satisfying index. Record it

    if arr[ind] >= ind:
        right = ind - 1 # Navigate left for smallest satisfying index
    else:
        left = ind + 1 # Navigate right for smallest satisfying index
```

You could possibly do with a couple of comments to help make it clearer what is going on. In particular, I would appreciate a comment explaining what your algorithm is doing at a high level, and where it differs from what I might expect. That is, for example, that it's using binary search, and that it doesn't return immediately on finding a solution because it needs the lowest satisfying number.
Also on code clarity, I find the variable name `last` confusing. What is it the last of? It could either benefit from a comment saying that it's the best satisfying index found thus far, or renaming to that effect.

`if arr[ind] - ind < 0:` is a slightly strange and unnecessarily complicated way of writing `if arr[ind] < ind:`. In python it is normally equivalent because python normally uses arbitrary precision integers, but in some cases where it's using a C style fixed length integer representation it could actually give the wrong answer because of integer underflow.

On a very pedantic note, this answer is potentially incorrect half the time because it ignores negative indicies. Python allows indexing to `a[-x]` to return the xth entry from the end. If your input array is `a=[-7, -2, 5]` then `a[-2]==-2` and -2 is the lowest such index. I think this is a failure on the part of the question setter, and I'm confident that they don't have it in mind because they asked for a failing return code that would otherwise be a legal return code. Probably a case of "Clarify the requirements" in an interview or development situation rather than "Change the code" but it's worth bearing in mind.

Comment: "you have your edge cases covered" - Not really, since the most obvious edge case, an empty list, makes them crash.